# Return combo box choices as a parameters in wxpython

Tags: python-3.x, combobox, event-handling, wxpython

i am working on following piece of code.
i want to return combo box choices as parameters and use in another function.
As combo box comes up with event handler i don't find an easy way to call it in another function.
my code looks like following

```
self.combo_box_product = wx.ComboBox(self.panel_1, wx.ID_ANY, choices=["one", "two", "three", "OTHERS"], style=wx.CB_DROPDOWN | wx.CB_READONLY | wx.TE_PROCESS_ENTER)
self.Bind(wx.EVT_COMBOBOX, self.OnCombo, self.combo_box_product)

def OnCombo(self, event):  
    product = self.combo_box_product.GetValue()
    return product
    event.Skip()
```

and i want call in another function as below:

```
def func(self):
    x=self.OnCombo()
    y=x
```

but as you already guess mistake is OnCombo() misses argument and program outputs error
Can someone help me, how to dealt with it

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call `self.OnCombo(None)`

```
import wx

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,None, title="Window", size =(650,350))
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        self.combo_box_product = wx.ComboBox(self, wx.ID_ANY, choices=["one", "two", "three", "OTHERS"], style=wx.CB_DROPDOWN | wx.TE_PROCESS_ENTER)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_COMBOBOX, self.OnCombo, self.combo_box_product)
        sizer.Add(self.combo_box_product, 0, wx.ALL, 10)
        button = wx.Button(self, -1, "Function")
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.func, button)
        sizer.Add(button, 0, wx.ALL, 10)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)
        self.Show()

    def OnCombo(self, event):
        product = self.combo_box_product.GetValue()
        return product

    def func(self,event):
        x=self.OnCombo(None)
        print (x)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App()
    frame = MyFrame()
    app.MainLoop()
```

N.B. This example uses `func(self,event)` because `func` is activated via a button event, this may not be the case in your code.

Comment: Thank you Rolf, though its not perfectly suitable for my application but it fits and showed some direction to proceed